# Problem with Tensorflow package when it's used by Lucid package

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

So I am trying to use the code in this link:

```
https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/lucid/blob/master/notebooks/differentiable-parameterizations/style_transfer_2d.ipynb#scrollTo=FsFc1mE51tCd
```

it's giving some errors when Lucid is trying to use Tensorflow at the first part where it tries to import. I tried to install some different Tensorflow versions and some different Lucid versions but still could not get it working.

Here are some of errors I get:

when I try

```
from lucid.modelzoo import vision_models
```

I get this

```
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/lucid/misc/io/reading.py in <module>()
 31 from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin
 32 from future.moves.urllib import request
 33 from tensorflow import gfile
 34 from tempfile import gettempdir
 35 from io import BytesIO, StringIO

 ImportError: cannot import name 'gfile'
```

when I try:

```
 import lucid.optvis.param as param
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/lucid/optvis/param/cppn.py in <module>()
 19 import numpy as np
 20 import tensorflow as tf
 21 from tensorflow.contrib import slim
 22 
 23 

 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

Comment: try asking a more clear question.  This is not enough information to debug your problem.  Imagine a person coming to this and solving the problem; there are no errors to read, no versions to look at, and it requires you going to a different website to view the example.  I'd recommend working on a minimum viable example.

Your question is asking someone to go to the colab notebook and figure out why it isn't working for you, that's not the purpose of this site.

Comment: the errors are too long so if I include them in the question, no one will even bother to read it. I will try to write more details

Comment: @Rob does it look better now?

Comment: your issue is going to be you're working in a notebook so it's tough to say.  run `!pip freeze` to get the versions of the libraries you're using, they might not be compatible

Comment: a quick google search says: https://github.com/tensorflow/lucid/issues/201 is probably your issue.  Lucid doesn't work with tf 2.0

Comment: yes that's right but I tried with tf 1.15 and still getting same exact issue

Comment: you'll need to restart the notebook to import a different version

Comment: thank you, I used the latest lucid version with tf1.15 and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for today, lucid does not work with tensorflow2.0 and later versions.
However, you can use tf1.15 or any older version and this should solve it.